# Cannot call value of non-function type 'IndexPath'

Tags: swift

I get an error when using the following code:

```
tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath(row: 0, section: 1)], with: 
.automatic)
```

Error:

```
Cannot call value of non-function type 'IndexPath'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `indexPath` with a lower case i. It should be `IndexPath` with an upper case I.

```
tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 1)], with: .automatic)
```